# sql server join with regex performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

i have to match 2 tables with a column that have values with similar values.
ex:

```
select * from(
select 'value**'c1 union all
select 'value11'c1 union all
select 'value**\value22'c1 union all
select 'value34\value**'c1 union all
select 'asd\value**\sdf**'c1)t1
right join
(
select 'value11'c1 union all
select 'value24'c1 union all
select 'value54'c1 union all
select 'value54\value22'c1 union all
select 'value11\value43'c1 union all
select 'asd\value21\sdf22'c1 union all
select 'asd\value21\sdf23'c1 union all
select 'asd\value21\sdf24'c1 union all
select 'rew\value21\sdf24'c1 union all
select 'asd\value21'c1)t2
on t2.c1 like replace(t1.c1,'*','[a-Z0-9]')
```

that s working fine, but performance with lots of records(>300000) needs almost a hour.
someone have ideas to have a better query?

thank you in advance!

i tried to add the condition on join

```
and LEN(t2.c1)=LEN(t1.c1)
```

but same slow result...

Comment: Side note: You don't need to keep repeating the `c1` alias throughout the union query.  Just mention it in the first subquery and that should stick.

Comment: yes, sql server like operator support regex options...

Comment: I get it now, thanks for commenting.

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to speed this up, but maybe you can include some background information on the problem that led to these tables.  Perhaps there is an option upstream which would avoid this query.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen: this is the real situation...before the values in t1 had * only at the end of string and i used the substring to join table...now is not possible(or i don t know how do it) and the only idea i had was to try with like

Comment: @elle0087 to be more precise sql server does not support regex, but it does support basic pattern matching using similar syntax.

Comment: Sean Lange : ok